Replace the `UpdateGraph` method from the deprecated Virtuoso package for dotNetRDF
I am using the dotNetRDF package to update a graph in my Virtuoso server. On their website, they say, "If you have a question please raise it on StackOverflow with the dotnetrdf tag." That's why I'm here.
Unfortunately, with dotNetRDF version 3.0, the Virtuoso package is no longer supported and I am supposed to use the generic SPARQL connectors. I am already doing that for reading data from the Virtuoso server, so I just need to replace the Update method, but am a bit at a loss here. I have a list of triples to be removed and a list of triples to add to the store. My old method goes like this:
public void UpdateGraph(string graphName, IEnumerable<Triple> triplesToAdd, IEnumerable<Triple> triplesToRemove)
{
  VirtuosoManager virtuosoManager =  new VirtuosoManager(Configuration.VirtuosoServerName, Configuration.VirtuosoServerPort, VirtuosoManager.DefaultDB, User, Password);
  virtuosoManager.UpdateGraph(graphName, triplesToAdd, triplesToRemove);

  // NECESSARY!! Otherwise, the changes won't be committed!      
  virtuosoManager.Dispose();
}

Quite plain and simple.
How would I implement this method with the new dotNetRDF 3.0?
I checked the tutorials and documentation of the dotNetRDF website.

As this question is specific to Virtuoso and its supporting components, I suggest you raise this question on the OpenLink Community Forum and/or the Virtuoso Open Source project on GitHub. Both are monitored by Virtuoso developers, among others. (ObDisclaimer: OpenLink Software produces Virtuoso, and employs me.)

Hello Ted, thanks for your reply. This question is actually specific to the dotNetRDF package. On their website they state that "If you have a question please raise it on StackOverflow with the dotnetrdf tag."
That's why I'm here.
